# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate

Tags: php, .net, ssl, curl

I did copy the latest cacert.pem to the folder curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem" but still have the error 'curl: (60) SSL certificate problem' in my localhost.

Comment: It is unclear what certificates the server uses and if the relevant root CA is contained in the cacert.pem you use. But, if the server is using a self-signed certificate (as usually the case with localhost) then it is not issued by a public CA and this not covered by "the latest cacert.pem".

Comment: I little bit understand you, so what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php.ini also update this param with same path to pem file `openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`, than restart wamp.

You can also put `pem` path inside php code:

```
// For CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/path-to-file/cacert.pem");    

// For Guzzle
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$this->client = new Client([
    'verify' => '/path/to/where/you/saved/your.pem',
]);
```

This workaround is dangerous and not recommended for production, but it is ok to use for localhost environment:

```
// For CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

// For Guzzle
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$this->client = new Client([
    'verify' => false,
]);
```

Comment: In what php file I need to put this code?

Comment: I did update this path what  you did write

Comment: The error `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem...` is not triggering initially on plain php page. This error is happening when using cUrl. So this is cUrl solutions to work without triggering the error.

Comment: Okay, I understand you, So what should I do?

Comment: Where do you I need to write this code what did you write on the answer?